# How to use the overloaded and original exp inside a member of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, member, overloading, exp

I am using a template class (`Pol<T>`) to calculate with polynomials and want to use a member function (`.exp()`) to convert a polynomial P into its exponential e^P.
Overloading the exponential function works fine, the compiler chooses the original exponential `exp(double)` if `T = double` and my own if `T=Pol<double>`, but in the member function I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Pol<double>::exp(double&)’
```

I cannot use std::exp in the member function, since I am using multiple orders of polynomials like:

```
Pol< Pol< complex<double> > > P1
```

I could use the overloaded exponential to make a workaround, but I don't see, why it should not be possible inside the member.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template < class T>
class Pol;

template < class T >
const Pol< T > exp(const Pol< T >& P);

template < class T >
class Pol{
protected:
    std::vector< T > Data;

public:
    inline Pol():Data(1){}

    inline const T operator[](int i)const{return Data[i];}
    inline T& operator[](int i){return Data[i];}

    Pol& exp();
};

template < class T >
const Pol< T > exp(const Pol< T >& P){
    Pol< T > Erg(P);
    Erg[0] = exp(P[0]);           // works fine
    return Erg;
}

template < class T >
Pol< T >& Pol< T >::exp(){
    Data[0] = exp(Data[0]);      // here appears the error
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    Pol<double> P1;

    P1 = exp(P1);   // this works
    P1.exp();       // this enforces the error

    cout << "P1[0]" << P1[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a `;` before the `{`. That might be your problem.

Comment: Also `template < class T > Pol;` is missing `class` keyword. Is this your real code? :/

Comment: After fixing syntax erros, it [compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d6a4aaa8ac226f0). Voting to close.

Comment: Try to instantiate it, and call exp.

Comment: Sorry, it is not my real code, so the errors RSahu and jrok mentioned are actually typos.
It compiles fine, as long as I don't call .exp()

Comment: I fixed and extended the code to a small program.
It runs only if ``P1.exp();`` is commented out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your edit, the solution is quite simple. If you have a member function, the lookup ignores the global template function. You need to reference it explicitly:

```
Data[0] = ::exp(Data[0]);
//        ^^ global scope
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c1af05d059d63f4)

If you want the compiler to see *both*, you could also use:

```
using ::exp;
Data[0] = exp(Data[0]);
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47103373d32c4d0e)

Comment: Its not my real code, so this error and two others are typos, fixed the post above.

Comment: @egladil86 I updated the answer with a solution for your real problem.

Comment: Thank You, that was exactly what I wanted to know.